# How do I url encode in Python?

Tags: python

I tried this: but it doesn't work.

```
print urllib.urlencode("http://"+SITE_DOMAIN+"/go/")
```

I want to turn it into a string with url encodings

Comment: `urlencode()` is for converting a sequence (eq tuple) or mapping (eq dict) object to a querystring.  For future reference, the Python docs are a really good resource to use: http://docs.python.org/library/index.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Were you looking for the [quote()](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) or [quote_plus()](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) function instead?

```
>>> urllib.quote("http://spam.com/go/")
'http%3A%2F%2Fspam.com%2Fgo%2F'
```

Comment: +1 because `quote_plus()` is probably the one you'll really be using the most.

Comment: For python 3, these functions are in the [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html) package (instead of urllib).

Comment: The example is not correct for Python2.  By default `quote` in Python2 treats "/" as safe and doesn't encode them.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`urllib.quote()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote).