# why html embeded pdf cannot support chinese-character file name?

Tags: html, pdf, encoding, flask

I use the "object" method to embed one "test.pdf" to html, and it works perfectly:

`<object width="600" height="600" type="application/pdf" data="./test.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" id="pdf_content">
</object>`

but once I **change the filename** **from English to Chinese**( "test.pdf" --> "测试.pdf"),  the html cannot display the pdf, the page is blank and empty. Why's that?

`<object width="600" height="600" type="application/pdf" data="./测试.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" id="pdf_content">
</object>`

I've tried many ways to solve the problem (e.g. change charset from "utf-8" to "gb2312"), but none of them really fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you need to encode the Chinese characters according to RFC 3986. An example in PHP would be doing

```
echo rawurlencode('测试') // Outputs %E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95
```

Also use `urlencode()` to encode according to RFC 1866 for query strings.

Comment: Hi @Tim, any idea how to encode the Chinese characters for flask, please? I'm using the flask to biuld my website. Thanks!

Comment: I've never used flask so I'm not sure but [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=flask+web+framework&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=flask+encode+url) led me to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5399164/2624391) on how to encode a URL in Python.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I've solved the issue.  The problem is that i used the instance_path in a wrong way...    Many thanks for your hint anyway!